# How to add slide-in effect to mobile css app

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an app with React and CSS. I have a navigation menu that becomes visible after the user clicks a button. I want to add a transition or animation to make the navigation menu slide in from the left rather than just appear suddenly.

My navigation menu looks for a context value `nav` to determine which classes to apply.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import style from "./Navigation.module.css";

// Context
import { NavContext } from "../../context/navContext";

export const Navigation = () => {
  const { nav, setNav } = useContext(NavContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(nav);
  }, [nav]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`${style.navigationBody} ${
        nav ? style.openNav : style.closeNav
      }`}
    >
      <div
        className={style.navigationCancel}
        tabIndex="0"
        onClick={() => setNav(false)}
      >
        X
      </div>
      <ul className={style.navigationList}>
        <li className={style.navigationItem}>
          <a href={"/"}>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li className={style.navigationItem}>
          <a href={"/"}>Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li className={style.navigationItem}>
          <a href={"/"}>Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li className={style.navigationItem}>
          <a href={"/"}>Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li className={style.navigationItem}>
          <a href={"/"}>Order</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If `nav` is true than the `openNav` styles are applied

```
    <div
      className={`${style.navigationBody} ${
        nav ? style.openNav : style.closeNav
      }`}
```

I am using css and want to add a slide in transition but so far have not been successful.

```
.navigationBody {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.95);
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  will-change: transform;
}

.navigationBody.openNav {
  -webkit-transition: 10s;
  -moz-transition: 10s;
  -ms-transition: 10s;
  -o-transition: 10s;
  transition: 10s;
  display: block;
  width: 85vw;
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Move the `transition` property from `.navigationBody.openNav` to `.navigationBody`. The transition will only be animated if it applies to both the starting and ending css states.

Comment: @motto I just tried and that doesn't seem to be working. Are you saying just move the five 10 second `transition: 10s` statements?

Comment: Ha, I also missed the `display: none` there. You'll need to get rid of that, otherwise the entire block is hidden as soon as the `openNav` class is removed!